# Java FileOutputStream access denied to a signed applet

Tags: java, file-io, applet, filenotfoundexception

I'm developping a Java Applet that must access the visitor's filesystem, so i compressed my `.class` file to a `.jar` file with self-signed cert, when I'm opening the `call.html` file with my browser (file where is located the `<applet>` HTML tag), I accept the security popup then i'm getting this error in the Java console:

> java.security.AccessControlException: access denied (java.io.FilePermission output.txt write)

I'm using a `FileInputStream` and a `FileOutputStream`. `FileInputStream` works but not  `FileOutputStream`, why?

Here's my code:

```java
try {
      AccessController.doPrivileged(
          new PrivilegedExceptionAction() {              
              @Override 
              public Object run() throws FileNotFoundException {
                  outFile = new FileOutputStream("output.txt");
                  inFile = new FileInputStream("input.txt");
                  return "test";
              }
          }
      );
} catch (PrivilegedActionException e) {
    throw (FileNotFoundException) e.getException();
}
```

I've tried many way to make privileged actions, `FileInputStream` is always working, whereas `FileOutputStream` isn't. `output.txt` is not read-only file.

Comment: Could it be that you are writing to a read only directory? Check the full path and the file system permissions.

Comment: I would suggest writing the file to a sub-directory of `user.home`.  It is a place that should be allowable for a trusted app. to write.  What is in the output?  (E.G. Game scores, the customer's billing record..)

Comment: The directory isn't in read only mode.
How to access `user.home` ? Netbeans show me this error: "Cannot find symbol: user".

Comment: Update: by using `outFile = new FileOutputStream(System.getProperty("user.home")+"/output.txt");`

i'm getting this error: java.security.AccessControlException: access denied (java.util.PropertyPermission user.home read)

Comment: @andrew-thompson I want to put some datas in the output.txt file temporary, is there a temp storage under the Java sandbox where i can create my output.txt file? I tried `new FileOutputStream("output.txt") but -> error.

Comment: `FileOutputStream(System.getProperty("user.home")+"/output.txt");`  Try changing that to `File userHome = new File(System.getProperty("user.home"));
File output = new File(userHome, "output.txt");
FileOutputStream(output);`

Comment: Still getting this error: java.security.AccessControlException: access denied (java.util.PropertyPermission user.home read)

It's like my applet doesn't have permission to access filesystem, it's strange because I've signed it and I accept the popup when browsing the HTML file.

Comment: I forgot to tell you that I got this error message at launch: docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/jweb/mixed_code.html , of course I click "No" but privileges do not seem to be granted. After several searches, I still do not understand, what is the mixed code? (Sorry i'm new to Java ^^)

Answer (score 1):

Access permission is granted with a policy file, and appletviewer is launched with the policy file to be used for the applet being viewed.

Creating a Policy File

Policy tool is a Java 2 Platform security tool for creating policy files. The Java Tutorial trail on Controlling Applets explains how to use Policy Tool in good detail. Here is the policy file you need to run the applet. You can use Policy tool to create it or copy the text below into an ASCII file.

```
grant {
       permission java.util.PropertyPermission 
   "user.home", "read";
       permission java.io.FilePermission 
   "${user.home}/text.txt", "read,write";
     };
```

Here is the full link for applets permission
http://java.sun.com/developer/onlineTraining/Programming/BasicJava1/data.html

Comment: Thanks for answering but i don't want to use policy files because I want my applet to be used by my website's visitors.